# joomla! 3. Add defer attr to default scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, joomla3.0

These scripts inhibit page loading.

```
/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?5b48a1fbde44016fe73f815fdae009c1
/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js?5b48a1fbde44016fe73f815fdae009c1
/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js?5b48a1fbde44016fe73f815fdae009c1
/media/system/js/caption.js?5b48a1fbde44016fe73f815fdae009c1
```

How can I add defer attr for this scripts?

Comment: jQuery easy extension https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy/ does help a lot with streamlining Javascript in Joomla. Not a real answer, but maybe interesting to you.

Comment: The chance is relative high that some inline scripts in head need jQuery, so loading jQuery in defer mode will lead to errors then. If you really want to do that then [here](https://joomla.digital-peak.com/blog/214-how-to-load-your-own-jquery-version-in-joomla) is an article how to overload jQuery with a custom JHhtml service. Just pass then the defer attribute and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using an "unset" script, place before DOCTYPE html>. See example below where I have also included how to unset css if you need that. Remove the bootstrap reference as well if you are using Joomla's core bootstrap.

```
<?php
// Remove Scripts
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->_styleSheets['/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css']);
unset($doc->_styleSheets['/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/system/js/caption.js']);
?>
```

Comment: They are not loaded at all

Comment: Thanks for checking, Tard. I actually added Jquery 3.3.1 (with Migrate) and Boostrap 3.3.7 under that, in the head. I still need to fix the menu from an old jquery_mmmenu script; but that's outside of this thread discussion.